# OAuth Verification Request - App Name and logo are not showing in our App OAuth Screen

Tags: google-api, google-oauth

I have a problem with the verification process of our Google App.
All requests from Google are done, (Domains verification, demo video). Still one thing which is Consistent Branding. Google are saying that our App name and logo must be displayed in the OAuth screen. And to do that I should put them in the OAuth setting, which is done.
But even after updating these details App name and logo are not showing.

The Google Cloud Trust & Safety Team, told me that this problem can't be fixed from their side, and send me this link https://support.google.com/googleapi/answer/7014572?hl=en , in where I find that I can ask a question here.

So, any help please.

You can't find below all the screen shot that can help.

[image: Email from The Google Cloud Trust & Safety Team]

[image: OAuth consent screen]

Comment: The app name and logo won't show up on the consent screen until you complete brand verification, as documented here: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/9110914?hl=en#zippy=%2Csteps-to-prepare-for-verification. Did you complete brand verification for your app?

Comment: I think brand verification is not needed for the logo & app name. Before this, I guess you need to configure your user consent screen. please see: https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6158849?hl=en#zippy=%2Cuser-consent